# Rewrite url / permalink for default archive - yearly / monthly

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, archives, rewrite-rules

I want to change the structure of yearly/monthly archive URL of default post type `'post'`.

As we know be default the URLs are like:

Default: `http://wwww.domain.com/2013/09`

but want them rewritten, so end up like this:

New: `http://wwww.domain.com/about/blog/archive/2013/09`

i tried following but do seem to work:

```
add_rewrite_rule("about/blog/archive/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?",'index.php?post_type=post&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]','top');

add_rewrite_rule("about/blog/archive/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/?",'index.php?post_type=post&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]','top');

add_rewrite_rule("about/blog/archive/([0-9]{4})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?",'index.php?post_type=post&year=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]','top');

add_rewrite_rule("about/blog/archive/([0-9]{4})/?",'index.php?post_type=post&year=$matches[1]','top');
```

I'd like someone to point to the right direction, need more info do leave a comment.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without adding rewrite rules by changing the `$date_structure` of the `$wp_rewrite` instance of the [`WP_Rewrite`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) class:

```
function wpa116030_init(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->date_structure = 'about/blog/archive/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%';
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa116030_init' );
```

Visit your Permalinks settings page after adding this code to flush the rewrite rules.

Comment: thanks, it worked like a dream.  i have another query, can we do the same (rewrite) for the default post type slug?

Comment: This doesn't work as expected if I change the "about/blog/archive" part to the name of my default category which is also the only category I have.
In my case the category slug is pressemitteilungen and I want to have the date archive urls to be like this pressemtteilungen/%Year%/%month%/%day% so the url for august 2021 would become pressemitteilungen/2021/08. Because wordpress use the rule for category names above the rule for date archive it sets up the wrong env vars and therefore I get a 404. If I could change the order of the rewrite rules I believe it would work. But I don't know how.