# Template Redirect to /2015 to use page template

Tags: page-template, template-redirect

We work with non-profits and come across this issue a lot. We need to use a page template for the url structure domain.com/2015 where we'll be adding an "end of year" report.

We're not using the typical date archives to list blog posts. I'm not sure how I'd redirect the template based on this.

My question is, how can I force the use of a page template instead of `date.php` or `archive.php`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you only looking to change the 2015 or all `is_date()` archives? have you looked at [`template_rediriect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) hook? What do you mean by "We're not using typical date archives" exactly?

Comment: I actually was filtering the $template right. I was locating the template incorrectly. It was nested in a folder and that needed to be included in the `array()`.

Comment: The only issue with this is that you're still needlessly running the date archive query even though you don't use the results.  You could [change the date archive structure](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116037/4771) to prevent this and add your own rewrite rule. You would have to also filter `wp_unique_post_slug` if you wanted to name pages with a year, WordPress would still erroneously think it conflicted with a date archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to override the yearly archive for 2015, then you can try the following:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) 
{
    //-------------------------
    // Edit this to your needs:
    //-------------------------
    $year = 2015; 
    $report_template = "tpl-annual-report-{$year}.php";

    //----------------------------------------------
    // Override the default yearly archive template
    //----------------------------------------------
    if ( 
           is_year()                          // Yearly archive
        && $year == get_query_var( 'year' )   // Target the year 2015 
        && $new_template = locate_template( [ $report_template ] ) 
    )
        $template = $new_template ;

    return $template;
} );
```

where your *annual report* template for the year 2015 is `tpl-annual-report-2015.php`.

More on the `template_include` filter in the Codex [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include).

Comment: you can also use the more specific `date_template` filter so your code only runs on date archive requests.